# Iterate over array of objects for group by Key and nested array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have the next array of objects:

```
originalArray = [
    {'id':1, 'date':'2020-20-20', 'emi': 1, 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7},
    {'id':1, 'date':'2020-20-21', 'emi': 2, 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7},
    {'id':1, 'date':'2020-20-22', 'emi': 3, 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7},
    {'id':2, 'date':'2020-20-20', 'emi': 4, 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7},
    {'id':2, 'date':'2020-20-21', 'emi': 5, 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7},
    {'id':2, 'date':'2020-20-22', 'emi': 6, 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7},
    {'id':3, 'date':'2020-20-20', 'emi': 7, 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7}]
```

I want to merge the objects by *id* and save the *date* and *emi* into an array of objects, please see the expected output:

```
expected_output = [
    {'id':1, 'date_emi':[{date:'2020-20-20',emi:1},{date:'2020-20-21',emi:2},{date:'2020-20-22',emi:3}], 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7},
    {'id':2, 'date_emi':[{date:'2020-20-20',emi:4},{date:'2020-20-21',emi:5},{date:'2020-20-22',emi:6}], 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7},
    {'id':3, 'date_emi':[{date:'2020-20-20',emi:7}], 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7} 
]
```

The code that I've allows me to group by *id*, but I still can't identify how to perform the merge by keys, and how to create and feed the array of objects *date_emi*:

```
let ObjMap =[];

originalArray.forEach(element => {
  var makeKey = element.id;
  if(!ObjMap[makeKey]) {
    ObjMap[makeKey] = [];
  }
 
  ObjMap[makeKey].push({
    id_cell : element.id,
    id_grid : element.id_grid,
    id_sector : element.id_sector,
    date_emi: {emi: element.emi,
                   date: element.date}
  });
});
```

The output from this code:

```
[
    null,
    [
        {
            "id_cell": 1,
            "id_grid": 7,
            "id_sector": 7,
            "date_emi": {
                "emi": 1,
                "date": "2020-20-20"
            }
        },
        {
            "id_cell": 1,
            "id_grid": 7,
            "id_sector": 7,
            "date_emi": {
                "emi": 2,
                "date": "2020-20-21"
            }
        },
        {
            "id_cell": 1,
            "id_grid": 7,
            "id_sector": 7,
            "date_emi": {
                "emi": 3,
                "date": "2020-20-22"
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id_cell": 2,
            "id_grid": 7,
            "id_sector": 7,
            "date_emi": {
                "emi": 4,
                "date": "2020-20-20"
            }
        },
        {
            "id_cell": 2,
            "id_grid": 7,
            "id_sector": 7,
            "date_emi": {
                "emi": 5,
                "date": "2020-20-21"
            }
        },
        {
            "id_cell": 2,
            "id_grid": 7,
            "id_sector": 7,
            "date_emi": {
                "emi": 6,
                "date": "2020-20-22"
            }
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "id_cell": 3,
            "id_grid": 7,
            "id_sector": 7,
            "date_emi": {
                "emi": 7,
                "date": "2020-20-20"
            }
        }
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group your array based on `id` using `array#reduce()` in an object accumulator. Then get all the values using `Object.values()`.

```js
const originalArray = [ {'id':1, 'date':'2020-20-20', 'emi': 1, 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7}, {'id':1, 'date':'2020-20-21', 'emi': 2, 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7}, {'id':1, 'date':'2020-20-22', 'emi': 3, 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7}, {'id':2, 'date':'2020-20-20', 'emi': 4, 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7}, {'id':2, 'date':'2020-20-21', 'emi': 5, 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7}, {'id':2, 'date':'2020-20-22', 'emi': 6, 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7}, {'id':3, 'date':'2020-20-20', 'emi': 7, 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7}],
     output = originalArray.reduce((r, {id, date, emi, ...rest}) => {
        r[id] ??= {id, date_emi: [], ...rest};
        r[id].date_emi.push({date, emi});
        return r;
     },{}),
     result = Object.values(output);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It works, Thank you!
However the syntax you use is quite new to me.
I would appreciate if you can explain what is the role of the :
1) `object accumulator`:
2)  `??=`

Comment: Object accumulator is the first argument of the array reduce which we are using to accumlate all the objects.

??= is Logical Nullish Assignment operator. This operator will update a variable with a new value, but only if that variable currently holds a "nullish" value (either null or undefined).

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an efficient way of solving the problem but it works.

```js
originalArray = [
    { 'id': 1, 'date': '2020-20-20', 'emi': 1, 'id_grid': 7, 'id_sector': 7 },
    { 'id': 1, 'date': '2020-20-21', 'emi': 2, 'id_grid': 7, 'id_sector': 7 },
    { 'id': 1, 'date': '2020-20-22', 'emi': 3, 'id_grid': 7, 'id_sector': 7 },
    { 'id': 2, 'date': '2020-20-20', 'emi': 4, 'id_grid': 7, 'id_sector': 7 },
    { 'id': 2, 'date': '2020-20-21', 'emi': 5, 'id_grid': 7, 'id_sector': 7 },
    { 'id': 2, 'date': '2020-20-22', 'emi': 6, 'id_grid': 7, 'id_sector': 7 },
    { 'id': 3, 'date': '2020-20-20', 'emi': 7, 'id_grid': 7, 'id_sector': 7 }
];

let result = {};
for (let row of originalArray) {
    if (result[row.id]) {
        result[row.id].date_emi.push({ date: row.date, emi: row.emi });
    } else {
        let date_emi = [];
        date_emi.push({ date: row.date, emi: row.emi });
        row.date_emi = date_emi;
        delete row.date;
        delete row.emi;
        result[row.id] = row;
    }
}

let arr = Object.values(result);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach. You can iterate each `originalArray` item and check if there is a previous equal `id` in the `result` array. If not, it means you need to create the new object. If there is an id, just push the data in the `data_emi` array:

```
// Where new data will be saved
const result = [];

originalArray.forEach(o => {
  // Search for index where the current id is 
  let i = result.findIndex(e => e.id === o.id);

  // If couldn´t find index (-1)
  if (i < 0) {
    // Push new data and get the index (i = result.length - 1)
    i = result.push({
          id: o.id,
          date_emi: [],
          id_grid: o.id_grid,
          id_sector: o.id_sector
      }) -1; 
  }

  // Push data_emi at index (i)
  result[i].date_emi.push({date:o.date,emi:o.emi});
});
```

#### Try it here

```js
const originalArray = [{'id':1, 'date':'2020-20-20', 'emi': 1, 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7},{'id':1, 'date':'2020-20-21', 'emi': 2, 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7},{'id':1, 'date':'2020-20-22', 'emi': 3, 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7},{'id':2, 'date':'2020-20-20', 'emi': 4, 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7},{'id':2, 'date':'2020-20-21', 'emi': 5, 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7},{'id':2, 'date':'2020-20-22', 'emi': 6, 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7},{'id':3, 'date':'2020-20-20', 'emi': 7, 'id_grid':7, 'id_sector':7}];
    
const result = [];
originalArray.forEach(o => {
  let i = result.findIndex(e => e.id === o.id);
  if (i<0) i = result.push({id:o.id,date_emi:[],id_grid:o.id_grid,id_sector:o.id_sector})-1; 
  result[i].date_emi.push({date:o.date,emi:o.emi});
});

console.log(result);
```